# Angular SwPush requestSubscription promise never resolves

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I'm trying to add web-push notifications in an angular application following the guide in https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-push-notifications/

I've added a simple `SwPush.requestSubscription()` like the following:

```
public requestSubscription() {
  this.swPush.requestSubscription({
    serverPublicKey: environment.vapidPublicKey
  })
  .then(subscription => {
    return this.save(subscription);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not subscribe to notifications', err);
  });
}
```

I've build the app by doing `ng build --prod` and use `localhost` so that the service workers will work.

The popup to allow/ block notifications appears as expected but when I click on Allow the requestSubscription promise is not resolved.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I've figured that another piece of code was causing the problem which I didn't think at the beginning was related, and this is why I didn't mention it in my question.

Before `requestSubscription` I created a method to get the current permission status `( grant | denied | default | prompt )` using the Permissions API (where available) as such:

```
public getNotificationPermissionState(): Observable<string> {
  if ( !('serviceWorker' in navigator) ) {
    return of('unsupported');
  }

  // @ts-ignore
  if (typeof navigator.permissions !== 'undefined') {
    // @ts-ignore
    return navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'notifications' })
      .then((result) => {
        return of(result.state);
      });
  }

  return of(Notification.permission);
}
```

When I completely removed the the `navigator.permissions.query()` call and just used the `Notification.permission` the promise of `requestSubscription` was resolved.

I'm not posting this as an answer in case anyone knows why those two don't go along and care to say...

Comment: I got the same issue where the `requestSubscription` does not resolve. Locally it works fine, but when I deploy to a server, it does not resolve. Still trying to figure out what the issue is